# VSCode/Jupyter interfering with Rich (log formatting library for Python) and I see an </> for each output

Tags: python, visual-studio-code, jupyter-notebook, rich

Here is what I am seeing, the sign to the left of each output
How do I make that go away? Again I am using VSCode/Python and Jupyter Notebooks

The outputs or like log.info("some text")
From what I have read so far it seems to be because rich is using markup that is like HTML and then Jupyter renders this as HTLM or something

```
import logging
import os
import sys
from rich.logging import RichHandler
def set_logging():
    FORMAT = "Func/Mod:%(funcName)s  %(message)s"
    logging.basicConfig(level=logging.INFO, format=FORMAT, datefmt="[%X]", handlers=[RichHandler(markup=True, show_path=False)])
    if sys.platform.lower() == "win32": 
        os.system('color')
    log = logging.getLogger(__name__)
    #log = logging.getLogger("mylog")
    log.setLevel(logging.INFO)
    return log
if __name__=="__main__":
    log=set_logging()
    log.info("This is a test")
    log.info("This is a test")
    log.info("This is a test")
```

[image]

Comment: Could you please provide some code to reproduce the problem?

Comment: I used the code you provided and conducted different tests in jupyter and vscode. It seems that this problem only exists in vscode. I put forward [this bug](https://github.com/microsoft/vscode-jupyter/issues/12254) in github and hope this can be fixed.

Comment: Thank you please if they fix the issue please post a reply here I do not have a github account, not a personal one

Comment: The update solved it. Can you tell me how to set up again this interference to notebooks output ? :) default `pip install rich[jupyter]` is not enough.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

According to the answer on [github](https://github.com/microsoft/vscode-jupyter/issues/12254).

Unfortunately, there is currently no way to remove `<\>` on vscode-jupyter.

Because it is a button that appears on each output. It lets you change the renderer type for that output.

You can use [jupyter notebook](https://jupyter.org/) if you like. This symbol `<\>` does not appear in my use of jupyter notebook.

[image]

Comment: just because the things are they way they are that does not mean that they are good or right :-)) thanks for following up