# Colorful notebook output with rich library

Tags: python, visual-studio-code, jupyter-notebook, kedro, rich

May someone tell me how to set again that colorful output from jupyter notebook without using `rich.print`? I use VSCode.
I've got this *feature* with kedro=0.18.4 and *lost* with kedro=0.18.5. **Kedro** requires **rich** as an dependency.

[image: colorful output vs white output]

I think it was a `rich`'s bug, because after update dependencies in my project I lost this *feature*. ;)
Previous similar topic with this bug: [VSCode/Jupyter interfering with Rich (log formatting library for Python) and I see an </> for each output](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/74632228/vscode-jupyter-interfering-with-rich-log-formatting-library-for-python-and-i-s)

I want to set it again, but I cannot.
I tried

```bash
pip install rich[jupyter]
```

```py
from rich import pretty
from rich import traceback


pretty.install(indent_guides=True, expand_all=True)
traceback.install(show_locals=True, indent_guides=True)

%load_ext rich
```

but I have still common **white** output. I can force it with

```py
from rich import pretty


pretty.Pretty(float)
```

returns

[image: Pretty]

or

```py
from rich import pretty


pretty.pprint(float)
```

returns

[image: pprint]

or

```py
from rich import print
print(int)
```

returns

[image: print]

but I cannot do it with common jupyter output without run `print` function like before update.

Comment: Have you tried to uninstall `kedro==0.18.5`, and install `kedro=0.18.4`?

Comment: @MingJie-MSFT, I wrote, I had these colors with the older version of kedro. Installing of the older one is not a solution. I had asked about how to color output of notebook the same or similar to output with kedro 18.4.

Comment: Currently import `from kedro.framework.project import settings` changes logger and probably accidentally the pretty print too. After import the default output from notebooks is prettier.